# cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Tags: linux, shell

I am just using the script to pull lines count from the file unfortunately I see an error and haven't got the expected count from the file. Kindly someone can help me to get the lines to count from Linux.

```
LINE_COUNT=`wc -l $TEMP_FILE | cut -d "$TEMP_FILE" -f 1 | sed 's/ //g'`
```

Comment: Does it have to be POSIX shell? If you could use bash or zsh, you could do a `((LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <"$TEMP_FILE")))` and don't have to worry about white space in the output of `wc`. In the case of zsh, quoting the variable is not needed (but not forbidden either).

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `cut -d " "`? Using a filename as delimiter seems not right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use input redirection instead of a filename argument, then `wc` won't output the filename, and you won't have to remove it.

```
line_count=$(wc -l < "$TEMP_FILE" | sed 's/^ *//'g)
```

Also:

1. Use `$(...)` rather than archaic `` `...` ``. They're more readable and nest more easily.
2. Don't use all-uppercase variables, they're conventionally reserved for environment variables.
3. Don't forget to quote the `$TEMP_FILE` variable.
4. Even with this method you still need to remove leading spaces from the output of `wc`. Or you could skip this step and just *not* quote `$line_count` when you use it, as the shell's word splitting will discard the spaces (my generally advice is to quote variables unless you have a good reason not to, and this is one of those reasons).

Comment: … good idea to use `<`. - The `| sed …` is also not needed then.

Comment: @Armali Unfortunately, it is. `wc` still adds leading spaces to the beginning of the output.

Comment: @Barmar: Maybe a matter of taste, but I would find `tr` more natural here than `sed`.

Comment: Interesting… maybe older versions of `wc` add spaces? I get spaces with `wc (GNU textutils) 2.0`, but not with `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.5` or `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.26`.

Comment: @user1934428 I used `sed` because it's in the original question, and no reason not to keep it, although I changed it to match just leading spaces. But I just checked one of my scripts, and it uses the "don't quote uses of the variable" method that I describe at the end.

Comment: @Armali I'm on a Mac, it uses BSD `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `awk`

```
wc -l $TEMP_FILE  | awk '{print $1}'


LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l $TEMP_FILE  | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$TEMP_FILE` as the delimiter argument to `cut` is nonsense; replace it with a space. Besides that, the `| sed …` is not needed.

Comment: If you use space as the delimiter, all the leading spaces at the beginning of the output will create extra fields, but you don't know the number of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk altogether:

```
$ awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

It is slower than `wc`, thou.